# Am i paid enough for my work?

Tags: freelance-websites, pay-rate

I am freelancer Android application developer, I got a project based on Hotel booking which I completed it in 20 days( **project based pay** ) and the client paid me 20k(INR) as I am new to freelancing am I paid enough? or paid less from the client ?

What will be the right amount for this project?

sorry if this is off-topic i am new to this SE site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a price is notoriously difficult and involves guessing how much your delivery is actually worth to the client. No one here can help you guess what your specific client in India could potentially pay you.

To begin estimating a price, consider what a normal monthly salary (including any benefits) is for a job you can get. If you have never been employed, find the data for India online at a site like https://www.glassdoor.com/

Normally, one would target a higher amount than a typical salary to compensate for client risk and time bewteen contracts.

Your availability could also be a factor; if you have more work opportunities than you need, you can obviously raise the price.

How desperate you are could be a factor. The more you need money, the more you might need to lower your price.

Comment: Thanks for the help @morsor  project is critical and and gave me only 20 days of time. I feel pay is low according to importance of that project. Any way thanks for the answer